# Single word for "it has no place here"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word for "it has no place here"?

One possible synonym is *unnecessary*, but that does not ring well in my ear

I'm aspiring to write poetry.

Comment: Can you suggest a sentence where to use the word?

Comment: This question is ***Off Topic*** (it ***has no place here*** because it's Too Broad - there are any number of reasons why something is unwanted, and this will be reflected in any number of ways to describe it as so).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - "it has no place here" and "unwanted" are very different. Misplaced comes first to mind.

Comment: "Incongruous."  (Try rhyming THAT one.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I don't think "off topic" is quite the sense that Laura was looking for.

Comment: @Oldbag - But Google "synonym incongruous" and you get a lot of suggestions.  "Discordant" is a particularly good one.  And that leads you to, eg, "cacophonous".

Comment: @Hot Licks: Unless you're psychic, I don't see how you (or anyone else) can possibly know what *exact* context/connotations OP is interested in. But even if you did, there would probably be many ways of expressing it (almost *infinitely* many, if we suppose OP wants to write *poetry*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Well, at any rate it's sexist to call Laura's question "too broad".

Comment: @Hot Licks: Like beauty, offense is in the eye/ear of the beholder. Me, I spend a lot of time solving cryptic crosswords, which are often *predicated* on unexpected/counterintuitive senses of expressions, but I don't go looking for that in "natural" English. You could call me "elitist" though, in that I don't think people who need help from ELU to express their thoughts are likely to make great poets (or poetesses, if you insist! :)

Answer (score 3):

A metaphorical application of *[alien](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/alien)* may communicate *it has no place here* poetically:

> adjective
>
> 1 Belonging to a foreign country or nation.

Comment: Actually OP refers to *unnecessary* as a possible synonym...

Answer (score 2):

Well, to some extent even

**alien, intruder**

might serve the purpose, depending on context and vision.

But you have to give us the context, or something similar to it.

Or

"**off**," as in "it feels off."

Answer (score 2):

*Alien* and *futile* intersect at *[extraneous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/extraneous)*:

> adjective
>
> 1.0 Irrelevant or unrelated to the subject being dealt with:
>   *one is obliged to wade through many pages of extraneous material*
>
> 2.0 Of external origin:
>   *when the transmitter pack is turned off no extraneous noise is heard*
>
> 2.1 Separate from the object to which it is attached:

*Etymonline.com* offers connotations that may serve your poetic interest:

> *[extraneous](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=extraneous&searchmode=none)* (adj.)
>   1630s, from Latin extraneus "external, strange,"
>   literally "that is without,
>   from without" (as a noun, "a stranger"),
>   from extra "outside of" (see extra-).
>   A doublet of strange. Related:
>   Extraneously.

Answer (score 1):

I like *[futile](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/futile)* as a synonym for *unnecessary*:

> adjective
>
> Incapable of producing any useful result; pointless:

Answer (score 0):

Unwanted - The influx of refugees is unwanted in our country.

Comment: @Amphiteóth I've just noticed this question has been put on hold for having too broad a context. Indeed it wasn't my mistake that the OP failed to give an articulate description of their perspective.

Comment: No indeed, but it was your choice to take a free shot at refugees with your example; I find it offensive. While you comfortably write your little answer, some people suffer greater hardships because of unwanted wars.

Comment: @Amphiteóth Give it a break! It was only an example, not a slogan to be used for propaganda. I don't, however, say one is unwelcome to do so.

Comment: @Amphiteóth So finding it hard to settle in some new place, are you?

Answer (score 0):

Does "misplaced" work for you? Ill fit?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a vivid and literal-minded word, consider *ectopic*.